# Proof of Cauchy's theorem for a rectangle.

Tags: complex-analysis, intuition, contour-integration, analytic-functions

I am a graduate student of mathematics.I am stuck with the proof of Cauchy's theorem for a rectangle.It does not seem intuitive to me although the statement is intuitive:

Let $f$ be analytic in a domain containing rectangle $C$ and its interior then $\int_C f(z)dz=0$.

I am looking for a proof of this theorem that is intuitively obvious.Can someone suggest any book for that.I have already referred to complex analysis by Ponnusamy-Silverman but that did not help me much.

Comment: Probably the most intuitive proof is the proof using Green's theorem, although it assumes $f$ is $C^1$

Comment: @MichaelBarz $f$ is not $C^1$ here

Comment: @KishalaySarkar See Goursat's theorem which says that of $f \colon \Omega \to \mathbb{C}$ is complex differentiable at every point in $\Omega$, then $f$ is $C^1$ and therefore is holomorphic on $\Omega$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This book gives a few different proofs:
https://mtaylor.web.unc.edu/notes/complex-analysis-course/

If you know Stoke's theorem (or just Green's theorem in this case), then you can note that we have the complex valued one form $f\,dz = f(dx + i\,dy) = f\,dx + if\,dy$. Thus $d(f dz) = d(f\,dx + if\,dy) = (if_x - f_y)\,dx \wedge dy$. The Cauchy-Riemann equations say that $f$ is holomorphic if and only if $if_x = f_y$. Thus $f$ is holomorphic if and only if $d(f\,dz) = 0$.

Comment: Why is $dz=dx+idy$

Comment: @KishalaySarkar We have the complex valued $0$-form $z \colon R \to \mathbb{C}$ defined by $z(x, y) = x + iy$. Thus $dz = dx + i\,dy$. If you inspect the definition of the contour integral, you can see that $dz$ behaves this way.